# vim autocmd not working

Tags: vim, vimrc

Here is my vimrc file:

```
set nocompatible           
filetype  on               

function Dateinsert()
        $read !date
endfunction

:autocmd FileWritePre * :call Dateinsert()
```

I expected to insert a timestamp every time write to a file. But it never works. How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`:help FileWritePre` gives you a hint:

> ```
> FileWritePre  Before writing to a file, when not writing the whole buffer.
> ```

The right autocmd event for normal `:write`s is `BufWritePre`:

> ```
> BufWrite or BufWritePre       Before writing the whole buffer to a file.
> ```